# Error when assigning largest 4 bytes and 8 bytes integers

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I am learning Fortran. I came across this error but I don't know the reason for this.

```
INTEGER*1 :: i1
INTEGER*2 :: i2
INTEGER*4 :: i3
INTEGER*8 :: i4

i1 = 2**7 - 1
i2 = 2**15 - 1

i3 = 2**31 - 1 ! giving error
i4 = 2**63 - 1 ! giving error

i4 = 2**31 - 1 ! this also giving error
```

Even though the variable sizes support the assigned values, I am getting Arithmetic flow error.

I am using gfortran 4.8 compiler. What is happening?

Comment: 2**31 is an arithmetic overflow. Did you try: i3 = huge(i3)

Comment: Don't learn the non-standard way of specifying the kind of a variable, such as `INTEGER*4`.  Learn the use of `kind=`, `selected_int_kind` (and it's relatives) and the parameters, such as `real64`, provided by the standard intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that the expressions on the right are computed using the size of the default literal (4 bytes likely), regardless of the type of the variable on the left.  Further each subexpression must be computable, that is while `2**31-1` fits in 4 bytes, `2**31` does not and throws an error.

assuming you want to see the arithmetic rather than using `huge()`
one approach is to do this:

```
 integer*8 i
 i=2
 i=(i**62-1)*2+1
```

or

```
 integer,parameter::i8=selected_int_kind(18)
 integer(kind=i8) i
 i=(2_i8**62-1)*2+1
```